# How do i change properties of a navigation bar item programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

This is not a problem. I just want to know if there is a way to change the font color and font size of a navigation bar item programmatically and not through the storyboard. I have a navigation controller setup in the storyboard like so:

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zdjj.png)

I need to change the color and font size of the label "Flash Chat"

[Chat Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAt4F.png)

Each of the view controller is linked to a swift file of same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to set title attributes in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
       navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
                                                          .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `ViewController` is attached to `NavigationController`, then you can use this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
```